# Firebase data only loading after logging in and out

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an issue with loading data with firebase and react native. When I initially go to the screen no data is shown. Although, if I go back to the login screen and then log back in the data I was looking for is shown.

The code is as follows :
For the useeffect hook:

```
const ChatRooms = ({navigation}) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    const [selectTitle, setTitle] = React.useState(new Map());
    useEffect(() => {
      const chatTitles = [];
      const chats = firebaseSDK.loadChatRooms();
      for(let i=0; i <chats.length; i++){
        chatTitles.push({title: chats[i]});
      }
      setData(chatTitles);
    }, []);
```

For the loadChatRooms :

```
  loadChatRooms(){
   const chatrooms = firebase.database().ref();
   let check = [];
   chatrooms.orderByKey()
   .on("value", (data) => {
    check = Object.keys(data.val());
    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
    return check;
  };
```

I am struggling to find the issue. I am assuming it has something to do with firebase/useeffect interaction.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you fail to handle the fact that data is loaded asynchronously.

The easiest way to show how to fix this is by putting the code that loads the data into yoru `ChatRooms`:

```
const ChatRooms = ({navigation}) => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    const [selectTitle, setTitle] = React.useState(new Map());
    useEffect(() => {
      const ref = firebase.database().ref();
      ref.orderByKey().on("value", (data) => {
        const chatTitles = [];
        chats = Object.keys(data.val());
        for(let i=0; i <chats.length; i++){
          chatTitles.push({title: chats[i]});
        }
        setData(chatTitles);
      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      });
    }, []);
```

By moving the code that processes the data into the `on()` callback, it gets executed once the data has loaded. A fun side-effect of this, is that it also will update the state whenever the data changes in the database.

You can give this a try by changing one of the titles in your database, and watching the UI update in near realtime. And this will of course also work once you have multiple users, all writing messages to the database.

---

A slight improvement is to iterate over the results with the built-in `forEach` operator, which ensures the order will be consistent on all platforms (and also when you order on other properties):

```
  const ref = firebase.database().ref();
  ref.orderByKey().on("value", (data) => {
    const chatTitles = [];
    data.forEach((child) => {
      chatTitles.push({title: child.val()});
    });
    setData(chatTitles);
  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  });
```

Comment: Awesome it worked great! Thank you for the help I really appreciate it!

Comment: I upvoted it, but my rep is still low. I hit that check mark now as well.